# Instead of run shortcut Eclipse shows shortcut in blue popup

Tags: eclipse

I have defined custom shortcut in **General -> Key** dialog for "Show Whitespace character". Key is **Ctrl-`** (Ctrl and the key above Tab). In Eclipse Helios, shortcut have worked OK.

After upgrade to Fedora 17 and Eclipse Juno instead of showing Whitespace characters, Eclipse shows up blue popup. I have to press enter and then action is activated. The same popup is activated if I press Esc but with two options: Format and Toggle Comment, so I suppose purpose of blue popup is to display choice (if there is any).

Here is image to describe the problem.

http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/2472/screenshotfrom201206011.png

I've been Googled for couple of hours but without any luck. Don't know how to name this popup either - popup, dialog, modal, window ...  and in combination with "eclipse shortcut", Google displays all answer but needed.

Does anybody know how to resolve this problem, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, if the problem is just a single shortcut, I think it is enough to change the *when* option to *Editing text*. It works for me, but after I restart Eclipse something destroys the entries in the keys configuration.

I think this is a bug, the key binding doesn't work well after this upgrade.

Comment: My shortcut was set as _In Windows_. In case when change _When_ settings to _In Dialogs and Windows_ everything works just fine. After Eclipse restart old issue appears again ... Returing to the original option _In Windows_ fixes problem until next restart.

Before Eclipse upgrade didn't have any problem regarding custom shortcuts. Hope this BUG will be solved soon.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the file `workbench.xmi` breaks for some reason causing this nasty problem. To solve my problem I've replaced this file with one from a new workspace and the problem disappeared.

The file is located in `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench`

There is actually a [bug for that](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=390298)